# Microsoft ToDo Graph API is sending broken JSON

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-todo

I'm getting the response with invalid JSON (brackets aren't closed) when trying to get the MS ToDo task for the user.  Also, API sends HTTP status 200 with that response.

Request/response examples:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists/:listID/tasks/:taskID`

```
{
    "title": "DELETED",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-06-17T18:33:44.3228459Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-11-27T11:36:55.8037415Z",
    "id": "DELETED",
    "linkedResources": [
        {
            "error": {
                "code": "InternalServerError",
                "message": "Invalid object within the collection response from workload for navigation property linkedResources with declaring type microsoft.graph.todoTask. Expected a JObject, but got Jtoken type - Null",
                "innerError": {
                    "date": "2021-05-14T03:13:36",
                    "request-id": "5b9445b0-7405-436a-8179-cac92a8af087",
                    "client-request-id": "5b9445b0-7405-436a-8179-cac92a8af087"
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tested in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)? What ever it gives as a response in Graph Explorer it will send the same data for any kind of platform.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma I've tested via the postman. But after your answer, I've tried to use Graph Explorer and it doesn't show a response because Graph Explorer can't parse broken JSON. https://prnt.sc/12wxrwp

Comment: I have tested for my data and it was working perfectly fine for me. Try with beta version and see if it works or not

Comment: I'm developing an application for many users and not all have this error, but some of them have it. Also, the beta has the same error, see screenshot: https://prnt.sc/12xdvto